# Dajaxice runnig with simple jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, dajaxice

Is it possible to run Dajax and Dajaxice with simple jquery ajax ? Does it interfere with each other in a bad way ?

I have few functions in Dajax and one app called EndlessPagination when simple AJAX occurs. Half of my dajax functions didnt work correctly while endless is working. In other requests of views.py everything is alright. Do you have any ideas how can I solve this problem ?
Mayby it is Dajax fault and I should not use it anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

¿ Is endless ajax calls synchronous or asynchronous ?, if they are synchronous the Dajax requests didn't launch before endless ends